# Invalid wav file no fmt chunk found after recording using naudio

Tags: c#, .net, audio, audio-recording, naudio

My motive is to record audio using NAudio, save as wav file and then mix multiple audios and play. For this i tried

```
  private void buttonRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if (sourceList.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

        //int deviceNumber = sourceList.SelectedItems[0].Index;

        sourceStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
        sourceStream.DeviceNumber = 0;
        sourceStream.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(0).Channels);

        sourceStream1 = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
        sourceStream1.DeviceNumber = 1;
        sourceStream1.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.GetCapabilities(1).Channels);

        //NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInProvider(sourceStream);



        //sourceStream.StartRecording();
        //waveOut.Play();


        sourceStream1.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(waveIn_DataAvailable1);
        writer1 = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter("D:\test.wav", sourceStream1.WaveFormat);
        sourceStream1.StartRecording();  

        sourceStream.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>( waveIn_DataAvailable);
        writer = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter("D:\test1.wav", sourceStream.WaveFormat);
        sourceStream.StartRecording();  
    }
    void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        writer.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
    }
    void waveIn_DataAvailable1(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        writer1.WriteData(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
    }
    private void buttonStopRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (sourceStream != null)
        {
            sourceStream.StopRecording();
            sourceStream.Dispose();
            sourceStream = null;
        }
        if (sourceStream1 != null)
        {
            sourceStream1.StopRecording();
            sourceStream1.Dispose();
            sourceStream1 = null;
        }
    }
```

Above codes works perfect for recording but recorded audios are not playing in windows media player but works with VLC media player. Using code below i tried mixing

```
   void Mixingfunction()
    {
       MixingSampleProvider mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100, 1));
        try
        {


            audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(@"D:\test1.wav");
                mixer.AddMixerInput((ISampleProvider)audioFileReader);
                audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader(@"D:\test.wav");
                mixer.AddMixerInput((ISampleProvider)audioFileReader);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            return;

        }
        waveOut = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();

        //if (flag == true)
        //{
        //    mixer.AddMixerInput((ISampleProvider)sineWaveProvider);
        //}
        //SampleToWaveProvider mixer2 = new SampleToWaveProvider((ISampleProvider)mixer);
        waveOut.Init((IWaveProvider)mixer);
        waveOut.Play();
    }
```

But it gives exception `no FMT Chunk found`. Now i don't know to do....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to dispose your `WaveFileWriter` objects before they are ready to be played. Doing so will update the chunk sizes in the WAV file header.

Comment: Finally mark i was waitng for answer from your side posted many question with tag Naudio. Now audio is recorded successfully but when i am trying to mix audio using mixsampleprovider it gives exception "All mixer inputs must have the same WaveFormat" . Why? . I tried to find tutorial on mixing audio but got only clue on one stackoverflow answer from you to use mixsampleprovider.